# Parsing a varied length serial message

Tags: c, parsing, serial-port

I am not delegating this to anyone as work but just wanted some idea/help in implementing the parser for a message protocol that I am working on. I have a message which is sent over the serial com port, so basically a simple collection of bytes only.

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------+ 
| MSG HEADER (5 Bytes) | ----- DATA BYTES (varied count) ----- |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

This message has a fixed starting five bytes for the **header** which denotes:

> Byte-1: **Fixed header symbol 0x81**
>
> Byte-2: **Fixed header symbol 0xFF**
>
> Byte-3: **Data Word Count**
>
> Byte-4: **Message ID**
>
> Byte-5: **Header Checksum**

and then after this, we receive the **data bytes**. The problem is that the **data bytes** can be of a varied count, but the count of these bytes is mentioned in the message's **header** which is the third byte. How can I write an efficient parser which should be able to:

1. Collect byte 3, 4, and 5 of message header separately in variables
2. Then based on the data count, i.e. message header byte 3, it polls the serial port until those many bytes are received
3. After receiving all the bytes, i.e. when full message is received, should denote COMPLETION (maybe just indicating a flag)

Comment: What is your question? Approach you have shown sounds solid. Just implement it, and see if there are any problems.

Comment: What does "DATA WORD COUNT" mean?  Is it the number of 4 byte words? or 2 byte words? Or bytes? Is it including header or only payload?

Comment: Byte-by-byte state-machine.  If the protocol fails, just go back to waiting for 0x81 again.